# Wiggly confidence interval with marginaleffects::plot_slopes

Tags: plot, marginal-effects, r-marginaleffects

I want to plot the marginal effects of an independent variable 'Shannon' estimated with a linear (lm) model. The variable appears both linearly and quadratically in the model, so the marginal effect changes along the range of 'Shannon' values.

To do this I use `marginaleffects::plot_slopes(model = MODEL, variables = "Shannon", condition = 'Shannon', conf_level = 0.95)`

I am very confused as to why my confidence interval is wiggly? I was expecting a smooth band around my estimated marginal effects line.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am the `marginaleffects` author. This is weird and I would very much like to diagnose the problem. However, it is impossible for me to find the source without diving in the model and data. Do you think you could send me a dataset and a **minimal** example (3-4 lines of code max)? Either post it on Github or send it to me by email: https://arelbundock.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have sent you an email with the data and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an artefact of numerical instability when computing derivatives. One solution is to select a different step size manually using the `eps` argument:

```r
library(marginaleffects)
plot_slopes(
  model = MODEL,
  variables = "Shannon",
  condition = 'Shannon',
  eps = 0.01)
```

FYI, I am the author of the package and exchanged emails with the original poster. This solved their problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Vincent!